# How can I access the brick id in ev3-g?

Tags: ev3, ev3-g

How can I access the brick ID ( or brick information) in ev3-g?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this identifier is used anywhere in the EV3 software or EV3-G programming language. Can you tell us why you would need it? Perhaps we can offer other suggestions... Note that you can give your brick a name in the hardware tab of your project (bottom-right)...

Comment: I want to make a block that works only in a specified brick.

Answer (score 2):

Only thing I can think of is to write the ID in a text file manually and use the file block to read the ID.
To do that: Use an application like notepad++ to create the text file. Make sure the line endings are just a newline character, not the carriage return.
Save the file with .rtf as extension.
Use the memory browser in the EV3 software to upload the file to the brick in the project folder of your program...
Alternatively, modify your program temporarily to write the ID first to file (manually select the value in a File block...), don't forget to close the file (second file block).

Comment: I want to give this block to another person. And I also want this block, doesn't work in another bricks

Comment: I don't think what you wish to accomplish is possible in EV3-g. There are other programming languages / environments (e.g. LeJos, ev3dev) where this task would be trivial.

Comment: This is the correct answer. There's no way to accomplish this task using EV3-G blocks.